# Linked List program hangs under codeblocks debugger but executes normally otherwise

Tags: c++, debugging, linked-list

I was given an exercise to debug a short linked list program, and while I've fixed it to have it behave correctly both with and without the debugger, there is a scenario which I can't wrap my head around from when I was debugging.

The following code fragment traverses and displays the contents of the linked list.

```
while ( p_itr != NULL )
{
    cout << p_itr->val << endl;
    p_itr = p_itr->p_next;
    delete p_itr;
}
```

Now, here's the strange thing: when I delete p_itr (pointer to the head of the list), shouldn't I lose the linkage to the rest of my list or dereference invalid memory during the subsequent iteration?

When I run the program normally, it displays all the linked list elements perfectly fine and returns normally (doesn't hang) -- when I use the debugger it gets stuck in an infinite loop, printing a pattern of irrelevant values.

For example, when I add the elements 2, 2, and 2 to the list:

### Normal Execution Output:

Output:
2
2
2

### Debugger Output (after holding down the "next line" key):

2
14166872
14166808
14161464
14155968
14167352
14166872
14166808...

Why does the normal program execute successfully? But I my main question is, why does the debugger fall into an infinite loop with these values and the normal program doesn't?

I am using Code::Blocks 16.01.

Comment: Are you sure >the normal program execute successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet

```
while ( p_itr != NULL )
{
    cout << p_itr->val << endl;
    p_itr = p_itr->p_next;
    delete p_itr;
}
```

has undefined behaviour because except the first iteration of the loop there is access to the already deleted object.

It is not clear why the nodes are deleted when the list is outputed. Nevertheless the loop should look at least like

```
while ( p_itr != NULL )
{
    cout << p_itr->val << endl;
    auto tmp = p_itr;
    p_itr = p_itr->p_next;
    delete tmp;
}
```

Comment: But I wonder:Why does the normal program execute successfully? so weird!

Comment: @Joe While being deleted the nodes can be still in memory.

Comment: what if there is a destructor?

Comment: But why is there an infinite loop when debugging? There is no destructor and I checked to make sure the program executes successfully.

Comment: @54skyxenon p_itr->p_next can have any value when you are accessing a deleted node.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Are you implying at it can fall in a loop this way? And does this "undefined behavior" necessarily have to act the same way with the debugger than regularly?

Comment: @54skyxenon The behaviour can depedn on how the debug processes variuos situations. But if the program has undefined behaviour there is no great sense to discuss what will occur.